# python - remove empty lines from end and beginning of string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, trim

I want to remove all empty lines from the beginning and the end of a string.

So the following:

```
s = """


        some identation here

lorem ipsum

"""
```

Would become:

```
s = """        some identation here

lorem ipsum"""
```

I don't like my solutions. I want something as simple and short as possible.

Is there something built-in in python3? What are your suggestions?

Comment: What solutions did you have then? Why is `s.strip()` not good enough, because it removes the spaces from the first 'sentence'?

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Exactly

Comment: @TheBrofessor: the second codeblock illustrates what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use a custom solution. Split the lines by newlines, and remove empty lines from the start and end:

```
def strip_empty_lines(s):
    lines = s.splitlines()
    while lines and not lines[0].strip():
        lines.pop(0)
    while lines and not lines[-1].strip():
        lines.pop()
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

This handles the case where the 'empty' lines still contain spaces or tabs, apart from the `\n` line separators:

```
>>> strip_empty_lines('''\
... 
... 
... 
... 
...         some indentation here
... 
... lorem ipsum
... 
... 
... ''')
'        some indentation here\n\nlorem ipsum'
>>> strip_empty_lines('''\
... \t  \t
...     \n
...         some indentation here
... 
... lorem ipsum
... 
... ''')
'        some indentation here\n\nlorem ipsum'
```

If there is no other whitespace than newlines, then a simple `s.strip('\n')` will do:

```
>>> '''\
... 
... 
... 
...         some indentation here
... 
... lorum ipsum
... 
... '''.strip('\n')
'        some indentation here\n\nlorum ipsum'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = """




  some indentation here

lorem ipsum


""" 

x = s.strip("\n")
print(x)
```

yields

```
      some indentation here

lorem ipsum
```

Comment: This assumes that the lines are otherwise not containing any other whitespace apart from `\n`.